# Does repmgr replicate "CREATE TABLESPACE"?

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

My standby database was shutdown because the tablespace was not available on the standby server.

**error:**

```
2021-06-01 15:16:30.061 EDT [21279] FATAL:  directory "/data/xxx_data_tblsp" does not exist
2021-06-01 15:16:30.061 EDT [21279] HINT:  Create this directory for the tablespace before restarting the server.
2021-06-01 15:16:30.061 EDT [21279] CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 2DDA/8DC6A528 for Tablespace/CREATE: 665042024 "/data/xxx_data_tblsp"
```

Does repmgr replicate "CREATE TABLESPACE" statement?

If yes, how do I enable it?

**software versions:**

postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.17 (Ubuntu 10.17-1.pgdg18.04+1)

repmgr --version
repmgr 5.2.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Repmgr uses PostgreSQL streaming replication, and that replicates everything that is stored in tables. Since tablespaces are stored in `pg_catalog.pg_tablespace`, they are replicated too.

The problem you encounter is that a tablespace is an object with a component outside the database: the directory where the data are located. You have to create that directory on the file system before you run `CREATE TABLESPACE`. Now streaming replication will replicate the `CREATE TABLESPACE`, but it cannot replicate the creation of the directory. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to do that either, since that directory should be in a mounted file system.

Replication is stalled until you create the tablespace directory on the standby server, as the error message tells you.